# PDO select prepared statement does not work

Tags: php, pdo

This is a snippet of code from source code, which I made to practice my PHP skills.  After submitting the login form, I try to see if the username and password that the user submitted using the login form matches with the one stored on database. If yes then "Your username and password matches what I have!" (obviously this is not going to be the final echo but just to see what echo out of the two will it bring). If I give correct creds (user/pass) or incorrect one, it echoes out "Your username and password DOES NOT matches what I have!" block. I don't see any problem with the code, I ran out of ideas.

Part of the code inside config.php (which I have included) is a setup of the database, with a table of registration and few fields, of which username and password fields does exist hence the names.

user is value of the name tag on login form for Username and pass is value of the name tag on login form for Password.

```
<?php
  include("config.php");
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
      $stmt->execute(array("username" => $_POST['user'], "password" => $_POST['pass']));
      $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      if(($_POST['user'] == $result['username']) && $_POST['pass'] == hash("sha256",$result['password'])) {
          echo "Your username and password matches what I have! <html><br /></html>";
      } else {
          echo "Your username and password DOES NOT matches what I have! <html><br />    </html>";
      }
  }
?>
```

Comment: You are querying using the password from POST, then checking the password from POST against a hash of the password from the result. It can't be both.

Comment: Thanks don't panic. I see it now. It is just a matter of doing it before the result rather then after.

Answer (score 2):

You've got one concept of password storage backwards: your code compares `$_POST['pass']` to the hash of the string in the database. So users are required to enter a SHA256 hash of their password? And you store plaintext password in the database? I don't think so.

It should be the other way around. You allow users to enter their password, then you hash the string they enter. Then compare that to what's stored in the database, which should also be a hashed string.

```
$pass_hash = hash("sha256", $_POST["pass"]);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
$stmt->execute(array("username" => $_POST['user'], "password" => $pass_hash));
```

You don't have to use an `if()` to test the results. Just test if the query returns zero rows, or not. If it returns any rows, then you found a match.

Also don't assume `fetch()` returned a row. If there was no row, it returns NULL, so using that row as an associative array will throw an error. Test to see if the row is non-null before dereferencing it.

```
if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // username and password matched a row
    echo "Your username and password matches what I have! <html><br /></html>";
} else {
    // no matching username
    echo "Your username and password DOES NOT matches what I have! <html><br />    </html>";
}
```

Here's an alternative variation I prefer: I just look for a row matching the username, and I return the hashed password string. Then I compare in application code. This way I can tell if they gave a legitimate username, but the wrong password. You don't necessarily want to reveal that to the user, but you might want to track it in your app so if someone is trying dozens of wrong passwords for the same username, you could lock the username or log an alert for the operator or something.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT password FROM registration WHERE username = :username");
$stmt->execute(array("username" => $_POST['user']));
if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $pass_hash = hash("sha256", $_POST["pass"]);
    if ($pass_hash == $row['password']) {
        echo "Your username and password matches what I have! <html><br /></html>";
    } else {
        // username exists, but wrong password
        echo "Your username and password DOES NOT matches what I have! <html><br />    </html>";
    }
} else {
    // no matching username
    echo "Your username and password DOES NOT matches what I have! <html><br />    </html>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is crystal clear. Also by testing the query if it returns a row, would it be something like this? if($stmt->prepare("SELECT....")->rowCount() > 0) { //do this }

Comment: I added an example of testing that. You don't need a rowcount, you just test if `fetch()` returned null.

Comment: The only differences between your last example and my code ($row vs $result) is that I did not wrap the $result around the if statement, and quite frankly I thought the if statement condition should only be boolean (returning true or false) but it seems that using the fetch() pdostatement returns array hence why I did not wrap around the $result with if statement. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: After re-reading your last example code, I figured what was going on. Thank you. With that being said, $row will return a row, and if it does -- it means username exists.

Comment: Right, because fetch() returns null when there are no more rows in the result set. If fetch() returns null on the *first* call, it means the result set was empty, i.e. no matching rows.